# JavaScript delete array[i] -- runs great in OSX but won't run in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos

I'm building a listbuilder app in vanilla JavaScript, and it's working on my macbook, but not on my PC.

What difference between Mac and PC am I missing?

The specific error in question is values aren't being deleted from my array in Windows. I'm not getting a Chrome or Firefox console error from Windows, but the "delete" function isn't removing the values from the array. Instead, it removes the LI from the HTML, but the targeted array value's LI reappears whenever a new entry is made and the unordered list is redrawn.

I've run the code through Firefox and Chrome on my mac and my PC, and updated the browsers as well.

The functionality I'm trying for is allowing the user to create a LI on the DOM by adding a value to an array, and then to remove both this LI and the array value by clicking on the LI.

My HTML:

```
    <div>
        <h2>Enter your Input!</h2><input class="feedback-input" id=
        "entryBox" placeholder="Type anything!" type="text"> <button id=
        "addEntry" onclick="addEntry()">Add your Entry</button>
    </div>

    <div id="outputBox">
        <ul id="outputList"></ul>

        <p>Click list item to remove</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var output = document.getElementById("outputList");
var list = [];
var entry = {};

function addEntry() {
  input = document.getElementById("entryBox").value; //Reads value from form
  document.getElementById("entryBox").value = ""; //Clears entry box for new text
  list.push(input);
  while (outputList.firstChild) //clearing the old displayed list 
  {
    outputList.removeChild(outputList.firstChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) //For loop to draw LIs in unordered list
  {
    var li = document.createElement('li'); //Creates li
    output.appendChild(li); //attaches li to the output list
    li.onclick = function() //provides list items removal function
    {

      function remove() {
        delete list[i]; //pulls it out of the array. Delete prefered to Splice so I can maintain original location of other array items.
        console.log(list);
      }
      remove();
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this); //pulls it out of the DOM
    };

    li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML + list[i]; //adds the entryBox value to the li
  }
}
```

I also put the code in a JSFiddle; the JS in the Fiddle didn't work at all, but I don't want to distract this into a JSFiddle lesson. https://jsfiddle.net/y3sjs7po/

Comment: Where is *outputList* defined or initialised? 'Cos if you don't, IE will create a global *outputList* that is the element with ID "outputList". Declare your variables and assign appropriate values, don't leave it to chance and browser quirks.

Comment: There are many, many errors in this code, better to post it in a code review forum. There's the *i* problem, undeclared global variable *input*, use of ID as global variable, embedding function in listener that should be a reference, …

Comment: @RobG Your comment came up in our CR recommendation comments feed; not saying you did anything wrong; but for the record, in case OP thinks of posting on CodeReview.SE site, this would be off-topic until the code works as intended :)

Comment: @Phrancis—got it. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I will make use of this heretofore unknown CodeReview SE site. I don't know a lot of best practices, and I don't have anyone to review my code, so I'm happy to find a place.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("outputList");` will return null as the element doesn't exist until the page loads, so your script will fail.

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/y3sjs7po/1/
(loaded after the body)

BUT, you are also doing it wrong in the loop.  You cannot capture the state of `i` in a closure like that. By the time the `onclick` event fires, `i` is always the last element in the array. Also, `this` does not refer to the element the event is from - you have to pass it in.  Finally, use `splice()` to remove elements in this case, not `delete`.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/y3sjs7po/4/

I changed it to store object items that contain details of each stored item.  Because indexes shift when items are removed, you cannot store the indexes and expect items to be at the same position.  To this end, I've change this line:

```
list.push({
    input: input,
    li: null
});
```

It instead stores the input value and list element in an object for tracking, and later removal.

```
var li = document.createElement('li'); //Creates li
list[i].li = li;
```

The part that makes it work is this:

```
li.onclick = (function (item) {
    return function () // creates a closure over the local `item` variable in the parent scope
    {
        // ... find the item's position (changes as items are deleted) ...
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
            if (list[i] == item) {
                list.splice(i, 1); //pulls it out of the array
                item.li.parentNode.removeChild(item.li); //pulls it out of the DOM
                break;
            }
        console.log(list);
    };
})(list[i]); // pass in the current item
```

It *properly* wraps each item (input and element) in a closure (by passing it into a wrapper function).  This can also be done using the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function as well.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording, changed it.

Comment: There are lots of errors. I started to answer but ran out of time…

Comment: I was trying your second JSFiddle, and it works better than mine, but I'm getting an interesting error. I entered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then deleted 1 through 4. When I entered 6, 2 and 4 returned. I removed 2, 4, 6 and entered 7, and the output was 4, 7. I entered 8, deleted 4, 7, 8 and received the output 7, 9.

Comment: Ah, the problem is storing the index - my bad.  The array indexes shift, which I forgot.  I'll fix it.  This is actually another error in the original logic - indexes will shift, so you can't store things that way.  You'll have to store object references instead, unless you want to deal with shifting indexes.

Comment: The shifting indices is why I went with "delete" rather than "splice."

Comment: I never would have guessed that, since you never checked if `list[i]` is even empty before creating elements for each item. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of mistakes that aren't outright errors but are poor coding practice. James has pointed out the error due to a closure, I'll cover some other stuff.

```
var output = document.getElementById("outputList");
```

Doing DOM operations when you aren't really sure whether the element exists or not isn't a good strategy. Wherever possible, make sure the element exists first. And don't use global variables unless there's a good reason, these can all be kept local.

```
var list = [];
var entry = {};

function addEntry() {
  input = document.getElementById("entryBox").value; //Reads value from form
```

This undeclared variable becomes global when *addEntry* is called the first time.

```
  document.getElementById("entryBox").value = ""; //Clears entry box for new text
  list.push(input);
  while (outputList.firstChild) //clearing the old displayed list
```

`outputList` is not declared or assigned a value, so it "works" because "outputList" is the ID of an element. ID's are made global variables (unless there's a conflicting declared variable or function declaration), it's considered very bad practice to rely on this behaviour.

```
  {
    outputList.removeChild(outputList.firstChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) //For loop to draw LIs in unordered list
  {
    var li = document.createElement('li'); //Creates li
    output.appendChild(li); //attaches li to the output list
    li.onclick = function() //provides list items removal function
    {
```

You are (attempting to) create a sparse array, but the above will visit removed members. You must test if the member exists before creating an LI for it. Using *forEach* will help is it doesn't iterate over missing members.

```
[...]
```

Here's an alternative function. It keeps variables out of the global scope and seems to implement what you're after. I don't understand why you remove all the LIs only to add them again, but that seems to be what you want to do.

```
var addEntry = (function() {
  // Shared variables here
  var input,
      outputList,  // Declare it so not reliant on ID to global mapping
      list = [],
      entry = {};  // Unused?

  // Keep in a closure so only one instance exists, not one for each element
  function remove(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }

  // return the function
  return function() {
    outputList = outputList || document.getElementById('outputList');
    input = input || document.getElementById('entryBox');

    // store the value of the input
    list.push(input.value);

    // clear for next time
    input.value = '';

    // Remove LIs
    while (outputList.firstChild) {
      outputList.removeChild(outputList.firstChild);
    }

    // Add new LIs for each member of list
    for (var i=0, iLen=list.length; i<iLen; i++) {

      // list is sparse, so only add LI if i exists
      // could use forEach and save test
      if (list.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = list[i] + ' ' + i;

        // Assign listener with IIFE to break closure with i
        li.onclick = (function(i) {
          return function() {
            remove(this);
            delete list[i];
          };
        }(i));

        outputList.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  }
}())
```

Comment: Your code definitely works for the problem, and I like seeing the array index value.

I'm still confused as to why the old code would have worked on one computer but not another--any insight into that?

Comment: The operating system should be irrelevant, browsers use their own javascript implementations that are mostly consistent across platforms. I have no idea why it works differently on Mac OS vs Windows, perhaps caching meant that you were getting different versions of the script on different machines?

Comment: That's all I can figure. I've been force-reloading to get CSS to update as I work, but maybe somehow the JS is working differently. 

Thanks for the attention to the question, though!